# GCD of common divisors in integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

> Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $r,s \in R-\{0\}$.
>
> If $g=\gcd(r,s)$ and $d$ is any common divisor of $r,s$, show that $g'=\gcd(r',s')$ where $r'd=r, s'd=s, g'd=g$.

I can show that $g'$ is a common divisor of $r',s'$ but can't seem to show that any common divisor of $r',s'$ divides $g'$.

What I got:

$g'dk_1=gk_1 =r=r'd \rightarrow g'd=r'$ since $R$ is an integral domain. Similarly,
$g'dk_2=gk_2 =s=s'd \rightarrow g'd=s'$

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Not all integral domains have g.c.d.s

Comment: Its an if statement i never said that all integral domains had the gcd property

Comment: Let $d'\mid r',s'$. Then $dd'\mid dr',ds'$, that is, $dd'\mid r,s$ and then $dd'\mid g=dg'$. That's all.